# sudo reboot -> Failed to talk to init daemon

Tags: raspberry-pi, reboot, init

My Raspberry Pi runs Debian Jessie. After installing Mosquitto I cannot run `sudo reboot` any more: it always responds, "Failed to talk to init daemon."

This error occurs even after uninstalling Mosquitto.  What could be the problem?

```
pi@fhem:~ $ sudo reboot

Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Comment: Debian introduced `systemd` as an option in release 7 (wheezy), and made it the new default init system in release 8 (jessie). If you prefer something else, it is possible that Mosquitto's dependencies have been defined to assume `systemd`, and installing it has caused you to (incompletely) switch init systems. You may now be trying to operate `systemd` with tools intended for classic SysVinit, or vice versa. You should have read chapter 5.6 of [Debian Jessie release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/armhf/release-notes.en.txt).

Answer (score 30):

Try:

```
sudo reboot -f
```

> -f, --force Force immediate halt, power-off, reboot. Do not contact the init system.

or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thanks that works. How can I get sudo reboot running without -f again? What happened?

Comment: `reboot -f` worked for me. `shutdown -r now` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick to systemd you can also do

```
systemctl --force --force reboot
```

Yes, you need twice the force.